# The essence of life! (A pretty easy What Am I)

Tags: riddle

*Many of you see me on daily basis;

I can be taken pure or mixed.

Some people say I prevent them from things,

others claim the opposite.

The small don't seem to like me a lot,

the big ones do sometimes prefer me over anything.*

***Who / What Am I?***

---

(This riddle might be way too easy, it's just something that popped into my head and I thought it I might share it anyways ;)
)

---

**Edit:**

After receiving so many different (viable) answers, this question might be considered too broad. To make it more clear, the title is another hint towards the correct answer. (Maybe it's not known that much, but at least I heard the answer being considered as the "essence of life" quite often.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can the answer be

> coffee

Many of you see me on daily base

> A lot of people drink coffee, or see people drinking coffee.

I can be taken pure or mixed.

> Some people put milk or sugar in their coffee, but others take it without.

Some people say I prevent them from things,

others claim the opposite.

> According to the [Authority nutrition](https://authoritynutrition.com/coffee-good-or-bad/), there is a lot of discussion whether coffee is healthy and prevents certain illnesses or not. According to some, it is even very bad. 
>  Also, most claim that coffee helps you to stay awake, but others claim that too much coffee makes you tired and sleepy. However, the last claim is not supported by many.

The small don't seem to like me a lot,

> Children usually don't like the bitterness of coffee

the big ones do sometimes prefer me over anything.

> Some adults really can't live without coffee

Comment: That's correct! The only thing clue where I was refering to another thing are the 3rd and 4th line. Maybe you can get that too (I will accept the answer in a bit)

Comment: That are the answers I was missing, nice! My perspective was it prevents you from (primarely) sleeping but also it makes you more productive.

Comment: Mixing coffee with anything but more coffee‽ That sounds like an awful idea!

Comment: Made me laugh @Addison ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing it's

> Water

Many of you see me on daily base,

> Water is very common

I can be taken pure or mixed.

> Drinks with water in them, or just pure water

Some people say I prevent them from things,

> For example, dehydration?

others claim the opposite.

> Water is involved in flooding, tsunamis and natural disasters.

The small don't seem to like me a lot,

> Insects in contact with have high surface tension.

the big ones do sometimes prefer me over anything.

> The largest animal, the blue whale lives in water.

Comment: Another really nice attempt! I guess I did not think as far as you guys so *lol*. Its not the answer I thought about though.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are

> Alcohol

Many of you see me on daily base,

> Bar/pub/shops/etc. Alcohol is everywhere

I can be taken pure or mixed.

> Pure alcohol or mixed with something(vodka, whisky, absinth, beer, etc.)

Some people say I prevent them from things,

> Alcohol can be used to disinfect the wounds, so it prevents the bacteria and other unwanted viruses

others claim the opposite.

> A drunk person is pretty much unstoppable

The small don't seem to like me a lot,

> Kids in general do not like alcohol

the big ones do sometimes prefer me over anything.

> Alcoholics!

Comment: Nice attempt, but not the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Pure alcohol is poisonous.

Comment: @Mithrandir methanol is, ethanol isn't

Comment: @Novarg It is, at least in greater amounts than a few drops.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't poisonous -- at least no more than any other liquor.  They sell 750ml bottles of Everclear  (95% ethanol) at my local liquor store.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer -

> Medicine

pure or mixed

> with water or directly as syrup

I prevent them from things

> helps to cure from diseases.

claim the opposite

> some believe medicine are useless.

small don't seem to like me a lot

> children don't like but adults like it as it helps to recover.

Comment: Another nice attempt, but not the correct answer.